# Spring Boot: Use specific alias form keystore to consume HTTPS SOAP webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-boot, groovy

I have a spring boot application in which am trying to consume consume HTTPS SOAP webservice which requires authentication with private key which is part of my keystore.jks as alias `client`

I have a spring boot application with below config

```
server:  
  port: 8443
  sessionTimeout: 30
  ssl:
    key-store: keystore.jks
    key-store-password: 123456    
    keyAlias: tomcat
    key-password: 123456
    keyPassword: 123456
    trust-store: truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: 123456
```

`keystore.jks` has 2 aliases(PFX) `tomcat` which serves the hosted service and `client`for authenticating with `SOAP` web service

I am seeing below exception when am trying to invoke java soap client stub

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 2E                               .......
https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4, called closeSocket()
https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2017-04-18 17:15:26.253 ERROR 2360 --- [-nio-443-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://tseiod-test.trustweaver.com/ts/svs.asmx?wsdl. It failed with: 
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.] with root cause

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Looks like `client` alias from `keystore.jks` is not used for authenticating with HTTPS web service, is there anyway I can force spring boot to use specific alias from `keystore`? Or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: suppose work around would be disable Certificate Validation if you are want and Install the all-trusting trust manager

Comment: disabling Certificate Validation is not option since we are consuming external vendor's webservice, the only to consuming it by authenticating with client certificate and private key

Comment: is it good to Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains

Comment: I've never tried that how do I do that?